# How to fix mpl_finance package for MatPlotLib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, google-finance

Getting this error message:

`MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The finance module has been deprecated in mpl 2.0 and will be removed in mpl 2.2. Please use the module mpl_finance instead.`

How do I put in place the `mpl_finance` package instead. I have it installed in pip, but what is the proper import phraseology?

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from googlefinance import getQuotes
import json
from datetime import datetime
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates
from yahoo_finance import Share
```

Answer (score 7):

All code for matplotlib.finance moved to a [separate repository](https://github.com/matplotlib/mpl_finance). Here is an [example of usage.](https://github.com/matplotlib/mpl_finance/blob/ffa70a5f9e8a30f7f260fc2941e59215a64fa139/examples/finance_demo.py) To answer your question:

```
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you. Spasibo!

Answer (score 2):

To import a module which is installed through pip with the name `x` you would mostly want to do `import x`.

So, here

```
import mpl_finance
```

or to get one of its functions, e.g.

```
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
```

Answer (score 0):

new version can be found here: https://pypi.org/project/mplfinance/